# All images from url stopped loading after Android Studio 3.3.1

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, imageurl

I updated Android Studio 3.3.1 and

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
```

In the next app run, ALL images that loading from url stopped showing.

- I checked website :OK
- I checked another app (not synced with android 3.3.1 yet) images loading with no problem.
- I checked Picasso, supposed not to be the problem as even in image loading I don't use Picasso, the images not show.
- I searched any references about it, no success
- Checked in other device (AVD, physical device) same issue.

**project level build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {

        repositories {
            jcenter()
            mavenLocal()
            google()
            maven {
                url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
            }


        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0' // google-services plugin
            classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1' //Firebase Crashlytics
            classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5' //performance


            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            //mavenLocal() must be listed at the top to facilitate testing
            google()
            mavenLocal()
            jcenter()
            maven {url 'https://jitpack.io'}
            maven {url 'https://maven.google.com/'}

        }

    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

I deleted Firebase Performance with no result.

**LogCat:**

```
02-24 02:13:11.857 11735-12045/eu.healthydev.quizhero D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1002K, 24% free 26052K/34232K, paused 40ms, total 40ms
02-24 02:13:11.957 11735-12022/eu.healthydev.quizhero W/Ads: Not retrying to fetch app settings
02-24 02:13:12.397 11735-12001/eu.healthydev.quizhero D/FA: Logging event (FE): ad_query(_aq), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=am, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=HomeActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=3297046615941659944, ad_event_id(_aeid)=3297046615941659946}]
02-24 02:13:12.427 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3
02-24 02:13:14.639 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero I/AppLovinSdk: SDK has been updated since last run. Continuing...
02-24 02:13:14.689 11735-12113/eu.healthydev.quizhero W/ApplicationPackageManager: getCSCPackageItemText()
02-24 02:13:14.719 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/webkit/WebResourceRequest;)
02-24 02:13:14.719 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.webkit.WebResourceRequest.hasGesture, referenced from method com.applovin.impl.adview.ah.shouldOverrideUrlLoading
02-24 02:13:14.719 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 24587: Landroid/webkit/WebResourceRequest;.hasGesture ()Z
02-24 02:13:14.719 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x000d
02-24 02:13:14.729 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.webkit.WebResourceRequest.getUrl, referenced from method com.applovin.impl.adview.ah.shouldOverrideUrlLoading
02-24 02:13:14.729 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 24586: Landroid/webkit/WebResourceRequest;.getUrl ()Landroid/net/Uri;
02-24 02:13:14.729 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0013
02-24 02:13:14.990 11735-12113/eu.healthydev.quizhero D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2031K, 24% free 26066K/34232K, paused 54ms, total 54ms
02-24 02:13:15.130 11735-12113/eu.healthydev.quizhero W/ContextImpl: Failed to ensure directory: /storage/extSdCard/Android/data/eu.healthydev.quizhero/files
02-24 02:13:15.140 11735-12113/eu.healthydev.quizhero W/ContextImpl: Failed to ensure directory: /storage/extSdCard/Android/data/eu.healthydev.quizhero/files
02-24 02:13:15.330 11735-12113/eu.healthydev.quizhero W/ContextImpl: Failed to ensure directory: /storage/extSdCard/Android/data/eu.healthydev.quizhero/files
02-24 02:13:15.330 11735-12113/eu.healthydev.quizhero W/ContextImpl: Failed to ensure directory: /storage/extSdCard/Android/data/eu.healthydev.quizhero/files
02-24 02:13:15.941 11735-12113/eu.healthydev.quizhero D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2012K, 24% free 26102K/34232K, paused 51ms, total 51ms
02-24 02:13:21.226 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
02-24 02:13:21.236 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("99AC4DB9D07891B91B6B4D7BE5F11ABC") to get test ads on this device.
02-24 02:13:21.826 11735-12001/eu.healthydev.quizhero D/FA: Logging event (FE): ad_query(_aq), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=am, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=HomeActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=3297046615941659944, ad_event_id(_aeid)=3297046615941659947}]
02-24 02:13:21.826 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3
02-24 02:13:21.856 11735-12001/eu.healthydev.quizhero D/FA: Connected to remote service
02-24 02:13:22.367 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2049K, 24% free 26100K/34232K, paused 66ms, total 66ms
02-24 02:13:22.687 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
02-24 02:13:22.687 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("99AC4DB9D07891B91B6B4D7BE5F11ABC") to get test ads on this device.
02-24 02:13:22.807 11735-12036/eu.healthydev.quizhero W/Ads: Not retrying to fetch app settings
02-24 02:13:23.378 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3
02-24 02:13:23.378 11735-12001/eu.healthydev.quizhero D/FA: Logging event (FE): ad_query(_aq), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=am, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=HomeActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=3297046615941659944, ad_event_id(_aeid)=3297046615941659948}]
02-24 02:13:23.548 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
02-24 02:13:23.548 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("99AC4DB9D07891B91B6B4D7BE5F11ABC") to get test ads on this device.
02-24 02:13:23.588 11735-12022/eu.healthydev.quizhero W/Ads: Not retrying to fetch app settings
02-24 02:13:23.988 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3
02-24 02:13:23.988 11735-12001/eu.healthydev.quizhero D/FA: Logging event (FE): ad_query(_aq), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=am, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=HomeActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=3297046615941659944, ad_event_id(_aeid)=3297046615941659949}]
02-24 02:13:25.480 11735-12010/eu.healthydev.quizhero D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1957K, 24% free 26187K/34232K, paused 62ms, total 63ms
02-24 02:13:35.530 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
02-24 02:13:35.530 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("99AC4DB9D07891B91B6B4D7BE5F11ABC") to get test ads on this device.
02-24 02:13:36.160 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3
02-24 02:13:36.190 11735-12001/eu.healthydev.quizhero D/FA: Logging event (FE): ad_query(_aq), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=am, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=HomeActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=3297046615941659944, ad_event_id(_aeid)=3297046615941659950}]
02-24 02:13:36.240 11735-12001/eu.healthydev.quizhero D/FA: Connected to remote service
02-24 02:13:37.241 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
02-24 02:13:37.241 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("99AC4DB9D07891B91B6B4D7BE5F11ABC") to get test ads on this device.
02-24 02:13:37.351 11735-12140/eu.healthydev.quizhero W/Ads: Not retrying to fetch app settings
02-24 02:13:37.872 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3
02-24 02:13:37.922 11735-12144/eu.healthydev.quizhero D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2089K, 24% free 26145K/34232K, paused 52ms, total 52ms
02-24 02:13:37.932 11735-12001/eu.healthydev.quizhero D/FA: Logging event (FE): ad_query(_aq), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=am, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=HomeActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=3297046615941659944, ad_event_id(_aeid)=3297046615941659951}]
02-24 02:13:38.092 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
02-24 02:13:38.092 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("99AC4DB9D07891B91B6B4D7BE5F11ABC") to get test ads on this device.
02-24 02:13:38.132 11735-12132/eu.healthydev.quizhero W/Ads: Not retrying to fetch app settings
02-24 02:13:38.573 11735-12001/eu.healthydev.quizhero D/FA: Logging event (FE): ad_query(_aq), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=am, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=HomeActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=3297046615941659944, ad_event_id(_aeid)=3297046615941659952}]
02-24 02:13:38.583 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3
02-24 02:13:59.223 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
02-24 02:13:59.233 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("99AC4DB9D07891B91B6B4D7BE5F11ABC") to get test ads on this device.
02-24 02:13:59.803 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3
02-24 02:13:59.873 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2040K, 24% free 26153K/34232K, paused 53ms, total 53ms
02-24 02:13:59.883 11735-12001/eu.healthydev.quizhero D/FA: Logging event (FE): ad_query(_aq), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=am, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=HomeActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=3297046615941659944, ad_event_id(_aeid)=3297046615941659953}]
02-24 02:13:59.933 11735-12001/eu.healthydev.quizhero D/FA: Connected to remote service
02-24 02:14:01.195 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
02-24 02:14:01.195 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("99AC4DB9D07891B91B6B4D7BE5F11ABC") to get test ads on this device.
02-24 02:14:01.275 11735-12147/eu.healthydev.quizhero W/Ads: Not retrying to fetch app settings
02-24 02:14:01.825 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3
02-24 02:14:01.845 11735-12001/eu.healthydev.quizhero D/FA: Logging event (FE): ad_query(_aq), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=am, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=HomeActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=3297046615941659944, ad_event_id(_aeid)=3297046615941659954}]
02-24 02:14:01.975 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
02-24 02:14:01.986 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("99AC4DB9D07891B91B6B4D7BE5F11ABC") to get test ads on this device.
02-24 02:14:02.026 11735-12152/eu.healthydev.quizhero W/Ads: Not retrying to fetch app settings
02-24 02:14:02.466 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3
02-24 02:14:02.476 11735-12001/eu.healthydev.quizhero D/FA: Logging event (FE): ad_query(_aq), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=am, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=HomeActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=3297046615941659944, ad_event_id(_aeid)=3297046615941659955}]
02-24 02:14:02.526 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2035K, 24% free 26165K/34232K, paused 45ms, total 47ms
02-24 02:14:43.036 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
02-24 02:14:43.046 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("99AC4DB9D07891B91B6B4D7BE5F11ABC") to get test ads on this device.
02-24 02:14:43.576 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3
02-24 02:14:43.576 11735-12239/eu.healthydev.quizhero D/FA: Logging event (FE): ad_query(_aq), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=am, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=HomeActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=3297046615941659944, ad_event_id(_aeid)=3297046615941659956}]
02-24 02:14:43.616 11735-12239/eu.healthydev.quizhero D/FA: Connected to remote service
02-24 02:14:43.826 11735-11789/eu.healthydev.quizhero D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2049K, 24% free 26164K/34232K, paused 41ms, total 42ms
02-24 02:14:44.057 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
02-24 02:14:44.067 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("99AC4DB9D07891B91B6B4D7BE5F11ABC") to get test ads on this device.
02-24 02:14:44.117 11735-12232/eu.healthydev.quizhero W/Ads: Not retrying to fetch app settings
02-24 02:14:44.587 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3
02-24 02:14:44.587 11735-12239/eu.healthydev.quizhero D/FA: Logging event (FE): ad_query(_aq), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=am, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=HomeActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=3297046615941659944, ad_event_id(_aeid)=3297046615941659957}]
02-24 02:14:44.727 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
02-24 02:14:44.737 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("99AC4DB9D07891B91B6B4D7BE5F11ABC") to get test ads on this device.
02-24 02:14:44.777 11735-12152/eu.healthydev.quizhero W/Ads: Not retrying to fetch app settings
02-24 02:14:45.228 11735-11735/eu.healthydev.quizhero I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3
02-24 02:14:45.238 11735-12239/eu.healthydev.quizhero D/FA: Logging event (FE): ad_query(_aq), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=am, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=HomeActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=3297046615941659944, ad_event_id(_aeid)=3297046615941659958}]
02-24 02:14:46.459 11735-12113/eu.healthydev.quizhero D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2004K, 24% free 26197K/34232K, paused 46ms, total 48ms
```

Comment: You didn't make any app code changes between AS update and last good app build?

Comment: Nothing at all. Only classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1' asked for gradle 4.10 (i think) and AS.

Answer (score 0):

I m sure its not the solution for all cases. BUT in my case deleted Firebase Performance, and Firebase Crashlytics, clean, rebuild was the solution. After that i implement again Firebase Crashlytics, everything ok. I implement Firebase Performance and had the same problem. So i believe its firebase performance problem with some other libraries or with my code. I ll investigate it more, and i ll post an update if needed.